# Sort() function of stl

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

STL sort function takes two arguments starting and ending point of array, then why we pass

```
sort(arr,arr+n);
```

and not

```
sort(arr,arr+n-1);
```

because n-1 is ending pointer of array

Answer (score 3):

The end of a container is marked by its `end()` iterator which points **one past the last element** not at the last element. For pointers it is the same. C++ uses the convention of half open intervals for most algorithms, ie `[begin, end)` includes `begin` but not `end`.

To sort an empty range you call

```
 std::sort(arr,arr);
```

To sort a range with `n` elements you call

```
 std::sort(arr,arr+n);
```

With `[a,b]` (ie both `a` and `b` included), it wouldn't be that simple to express an empty range.

Comment: I saw lot of beginners tend to use `for (int i = 1: i <= n; ++i)`, so the parallel with for range might be biased.

Comment: @Jarod42 I wanted to keep the "why" out, but that argument is simple and convincing enough.

Comment: handling empty range **is** the point IMO.

Comment: One notable place where C++ doesn't use half-open intervals is the `<random>` header.